Movie that starts with a motorcycle stunt driver that crashes on purpose for extra money
I think the movie is from around 2005-2010 but Im not sure about that.
Early scenes revolve around an older man making his living by doing stunts with a motorcycle. The pay isn't too good so his wife/girlfriend/manager (?) bargains some extra money for him to crash on purpose.
I think the overall subject of the movie is preparing/executing a heist. 
One of the other scenes I remember is the team the man assembled smuggling a book or painting outside a building, possibly a restauration facility. 
They do so by conceiling said item within another piece of art, shaped like a womans genitalia. 
The movie ends with the team playing tricks on one of their own members who wanted to frame them and take the loot for himself. 

You're looking for The Art of the Steal from 2013 with Kurt Russell.

Crunch Calhoun (Kurt Russell), a third rate motorcycle daredevil and semi-reformed art thief, agrees to get back into the con game and pull off one final lucrative art theft with his untrustworthy brother, Nicky (Matt Dillon). Reassembling the old team, Crunch comes up with a plan to steal a priceless historical book, but the successful heist leads to another far riskier plan devised by Nicky. They fail to realize each other's separate agendas when their plan goes awry in this con movie about honor, revenge and the bonds of brotherhood.

They hide the book in a sculpture of female genitalia. Here's the trailer:




Yes, this is it. Thank you very much!
